# Изменение функционала родительской темы в дочерней

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем привет, подскажите как быть в случае если мне нужно поменять поведение функции родительской темы, но в том случае когда автором не определена возможность доработки темы, ну например нет элементарной проверки function_exists, как в таком случае менять функционал? Переписывать родительскую и вести логи правок?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от того, что вы хотите сделать. Поскольку почти весь код завязан на хуки, то можно в дочерней теме отменять те хуки родительской темы, поведение которых надо изменить, и добавлять свои хуки с нужным поведением.

Comment: Да действительно хорошая идея, спасибо за подсказку